# Which is Better storing users favorites in DB or XML

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I'm working on application using ionic2 and angular js and it have added to favorites functionality and I was wondering which is best to store the favorites information in DB or store them in XML file

so my question is which is the preferable approach? I'm leaning towards the DB because I never try to use XML

Answer (score 0):

Xml Manipulation would be much costlier as its a slow process(provided if you have huge amount of data). Now there are 2 scenarios.
1) You are developing the app for your learning 
2) you are developing for a client.

If its for yourself then either choice is fine. you just need data whether in JSON form or Xml form so either way is good.
But if its for client then performance is a big key factor and that's why move it to DB create a service change it to JSON and then consume it. Best way to access data if you go by business rules.